# easyui return undefined from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-easyui

I make form submit, when I check in console it returns JSON data. But I can't use object in JSON data.

```
$('#ff').form({
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                url: base_url + 'Api/lapor/submit',
                dataType: 'json',
                iframe: false,
                onSubmit: function(param) {
                    param.id_item = sessionStorage.id_item;
                    param.token = sessionStorage.token;
                },
                onProgress: function(percent) {
                    $.messager.progress();
                },
                success: function(msg){
                  console.log(msg.status); //it will return undefined
                  $.messager.progress('close');
                },
                onLoadError: function(){
                    $.messager.alert('Error', 'Gagal', 'error');
                }
            });
```

I try `console.log(msg)` and it return JSON data
[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbdc2.jpg)

Comment: still return undefined

Comment: Try debug it with breakpoint, and type `msg[` to see the option possible like in this image [JSON data](https://i.imgur.com/jmnSs0x.png) and [possible option](https://i.imgur.com/Xr9sWBn.png)

Comment: @Kyojimaru sorry I don't understand. I check in XHR, it returns like this image https://prnt.sc/wn6k5y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log the return message using `console.log(msg.status);`, if it write the result as `{message: "Data 1 telah disimpan", status: true}` then you can call it by using either `msg.status` or `msg['status']`

But in your case it's logged as `{"message": "Data 1 telah disimpan", "status": true}`, so you should try calling it with the `"` included like `msg['"status"']` or `msg["\"status\""]`

```js
var msg1 = {"message": "Data 1 telah disimpan", "status": true}
var msg2 = {'"message"': "Data 2 telah disimpan", '"status"': true}

function checkdata1() {
  console.log(msg1);
  alert(msg1.message);
}

function checkdata2() {
  console.log(msg2);
  alert(msg2['"message"'])
}
```

```html
<btn onclick="checkdata1()">Check Data 1</btn>
<br/>
<btn onclick="checkdata2()">Check Data 2</btn>
```

**Update** Here's the difference between the `msg1` and `msg2` when logged using `console.log`[image: difference]

**Update 2** Because the return type of `jeasyui` `$.form` is a `string`, so you need to parse it first to a JSON / javascript object by using `JSON.parse` or the one found in the `jeasyui` docs section ***Handle submit response*** [here](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/form.php)

Comment: still undefined. my data when i display in console return like msg1 `{"message": "Data 1 telah disimpan", "status": true}`

Comment: @DVCorps if it's like msg1 in console then you should use the `msg['"status"']` because the msg1 when logged in console will appear as `{message: "Data 1 telah disimpan", status: true}`. Try to open your console inspector and click the Check Data to see the difference in the log

Comment: @DVCorps the one inside `success: function(msg) {` what did it write if you change it to `console.log(msg)`, not the one in the XHR

Comment: Thanks alot for your explanation, but it still not work

Comment: @DVCorps perhaps the `msg` returned from your log result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbdc2.jpg) is not an object, because it doesn't have the expand button ► beside the log results. Maybe you can try to set the `msg` to some global variable and try any autocomplete when you type the variable, or try `JSON.Parse(msg)` first?

Comment: I try `var msg2 = JSON.Parse(msg); console.log(msg2.status);` but it return `JSON.Parse is not a function` > Btw i'm using easyui

Comment: @DVCorps if you try `console.log(typeof(msg))` what is the result? If the result is string and you're using easyui try `JSON.parse(msg)`

Comment: string. it's confusing

Comment: Ok i try `console.log(JSON.parse(msg));` and it turns `(index):240 {message: "Data telah disimpan", status: true}` with expand button ►. Now how to return status or message value?

Comment: @DVCorps Here's what I've found using easyui [tutorial](https://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/form.php) and jump to _**Handle submit response**_ section, there's one step that you missed. The return value of `$.form` is string, so you need to convert it to JSON / javascript object with `JSON.parse` or using the one told there

Comment: solved, I try `var status_boy = JSON.parse(msg); console.log(status_boy['message']);` and i work. thanks

Comment: @DVCorps if it's already parsed to JSON object, you should be able to type it with `status_boy.message` too

Comment: thank you. but I use documentation from easyui that you give as solution